# self.navigationController popToViewController not popping to the right view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios7

So, I searched in all the issues on the site but non of them helped me..

I am trying to go to the first viewcontroler that I have (different than the rootviewcontroller) so I am using the method "self.navigationController popToViewController"

The problem is, the array "self.navigationController.viewControllers" is filled with 5 items so I know that the view controller is there but still it always goes to the previous view..

I tried also "popToRootViewControllerAnimated" just for testing and it also have the same behavior

Please tell me !!

Comment: Please provide some code to see exactly how you are trying to use popToViewController:animated. Also it may be useful to show us how you are populating your view controller stack.

Comment: This is how I am trying to pop to view controller: 

NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
            id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[GuestTerminalController class]]){
                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }

And I am using : [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];

to populate the stack..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using below?

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```